# Why the grave accent is used when passing the mod function to map?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell, but I didn't find an answer to this.

Why the grave accent is used to pass the `mod` function to map like in the example? I saw other cases with other functions where it isn't needed.

```
map (`mod` 3) [1..6]   -- result is [1,2,0,1,2,0]
```

If I pass without the grave accent, the result is completely different.

```
map (mod 3) [1..6]    -- result is [0,1,0,3,3,3]
```

Comment: These are also called "backticks," which might make it easier to search for them - e.g. here: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/functional-programming.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The accent "makes the function behave like an operator". Eg:

```
mod a b == a `mod` b
```

so

```
(mod 3) == mod 3 ?
```

and

```
(`mod` 3) == mod ? 3
```

Comment: Just to add, brackets make an operator act like a function, I.e. `1 + 2 == (+) 1 2`, which comes up with functions like `foldr` occasionally.

Comment: Another addendum: The intended effect here is the same as `(flip mod 3)`, what's considered easier to read probably depends on your mood though.

Comment: @Cubic In this case, `mod` is usually used as an infix operator when speaking, so here I'd definitely go with backticks here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to explicitly sure about what are you thinking about, (I always do mine since I am still in learning phase too), you can always use [anonymous function](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Anonymous_function)  (I think sometimes called *lambda expression*, but not sure)

```
> map (\x -> x `mod` 3) [1..10]
[1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1]

> map (\x -> 3 `mod` x) [1..10]
[0,1,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]

> map (\x -> mod x 3) [1..10]
[1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1]

> map (\x -> mod 3 x) [1..10]
[0,1,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
```